# How to run background tasks in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm developing a small web service with Flask which needs to run background tasks, preferably from a task queue.  However, after googling the subject the only results were essentially Celery and Redis Queue, which apparently require separate queuing services and thus are options that are far too heavy and convoluted to deploy.  As all I'm looking for is a simple background task queue that enables tasks to be queued and executed on separate threads/processes, does anyone know if there is anything like this available in Python?

Comment: What do you expect to handle the queue instead of a queue system like Redis, RabbitMQ, or SQS?

Comment: @jordanm My concern is that I shouldn't require a separate service, let alone a commercial service like SQS, just to run background tasks in a small web service.

Comment: I am not sure how it would work at all without a broker. Some other language's job systems like Rail's delayed jobs support using a database as the broker, but Celery does not.

Comment: In python3 you have thread and process pools. Maybe it's sufficient for your use case. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: I would highly advise against subprocess or thread calls within your flask controllers.

Comment: @jordanm why don't you like thread calls within flask controllers?

Comment: @RAM Because errors in threaded code can not only cause the current request to fail, but also cause problems for the running container (eg uwsgi, gunicorn). `uwsgi` doesn't even allow threads by default. It also makes the code harder to test and maintain. In this case there is already a widely accepted standard to accomplish this goal: `Celery`.

Answer (score 10):

```
import threading
import time

class BackgroundTasks(threading.Thread):
    def run(self,*args,**kwargs):
        while True:
            print('Hello')
            time.sleep(1)

t = BackgroundTasks()
t.start()
```

After the while statement , you can put the code you want to run in background. Maybe deleting some models , sending email or whatever.

Comment: When I quit the program the background task also quits. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

The [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library might be what you are looking for

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('Hello ...')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... World!')

# Python 3.7+
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **FastAPI**, there is already implementation of [BackgroundTasks](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/)

You **don't** need to implement **Threading** and **Queues** for doing background tasks after receiving the request.

Code Implementation:

```
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

# function that will run in background after sending the response
def write_notification(email: str, message=""):
    with open("log.txt", mode="w") as email_file:
        content = f"notification for {email}: {message}"
        email_file.write(content)


@app.post("/send-notification/{email}")
async def send_notification(email: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(write_notification, email, message="some notification")
    return {"message": "Tasks are happening in background"}
```